# Reduce the size of minimum finger distance in zoom out

Tags: java, android, android-imageview, pinchzoom

I have `ScaleGestureDetector` on an `ImageView` for pinch zoom feature. But by default zoom out feature works up to a certain distance of two fingers. To zoom out again I have to start pinch zoom again. How can I overcome these two fingers distance limitation? So that my zoom-out will be smooth.

```
@Override
public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
   mScaleFactor = detector.getScaleFactor();

    // Don't let the object get too small or too large.
    // mScaleFactor = Math.max(0.1f, Math.min(mScaleFactor, 5.0f));
    scaleImage(mScaleFactor, detector.getFocusX(), detector.getFocusY(), true);
    invalidate();
    //matrix.setScale(detector.getScaleFactor(),detector.getScaleFactor());
    return true;
}
```